# OpenCV CascadeClassifier C++ Interface in Multiple Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I would like to run an OpenCV C++ Interface using the CascadeClassifier Objects in multiple threads.

The way my program works is my main thread loads "some_file.xml" into a CascadeClassifier object. Three or more threads are spawned and they are passed the cascade object. The program soon crashes thereafter. I have done several tests and concluded that the CascadeClassifier object is not thread-safe when doing a "detectmultiscale" function.

I would like to avoid having to read the same file off of the hard drive every time a new thread is spawned. How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with LBP cascade of with Haar cascade stored in new format then you can avoid reading cascade from file system for each new thread:

Load cascade into memory:

```
cv::FileStorage fs(path_to_cascade_file, cv::FileStorage::READ);
if (!fs.isOpened())
    HandleError();
```

Next pass fs object to the each new thread and create CascadeClassifier object:

```
cv::CascadeClassifier cc;
if (!cc.read(fs.getFirstTopLevelNode())
    HandleError2();
```

Comment: How do you know if the xml file is in the "new" format or not? Were they all converted to the newest format in the latest release?

Comment: All haar cascades coming with OpenCV are stored in old format. And most likely they will never be converted to new format (but if you want you can write a converter and contribute). Simplest criteria to identify new format - search for the tag `<stageType>BOOST</stageType>` in the cascade file - it is mandatory for new format.

Comment: Where can I find information about both formats to write a converter?