# Multithreaded Face Detection stops working

Tags: multithreading, qt, opencv, qthread

I am trying to implement a multithreaded face detector. The problem is after capturing and processing some frames from camera, the program unexpectedly stops working. Here is the code:

```
cascadeClassifier cad;

class myThread: public QThread
{
private:
    Mat threadRoi;
    vector<Rect> faces;
protected:
    void run()
    {
        cad.detectMultiScale(threadRoi,faces,1.4,4,CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING|CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT,Size(30,30));
        if ( !faces.empty())
                  rectangle(threadRoi,faces[0],Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    }
public:
    myThread(Mat &r)
    {
        threadRoi = r;
    }
    vector<Rect> getFaces()
    {
        return faces;
    }
};
int main()
{
    cad.load("C:/opencv/data/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    Mat frame;
    while(1)
    {
       if(!cap.read(frame))   break;
       cvtColor(frame,frame_gray));
       myThread a(frame_gray(Rect(0,0,frame.cols/2,frame.rows/2));
       myThread b(frame_gray(Rect(frame.cols/4,0,frame.cols/2,frame.rows/2));
       myThread c(frame_gray(Rect(frame.cols/2,0,frame.cols/2,frame.rows/2));
       a.start();
       b.start();
       c.start();
       a.wait();
       b.wait();
       c.wait();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I noticed that if I use a common cascadeClassifier for all threads then this problem occurs. When I gave each thread seperate cascadeClassifiers as their own private class members then they were working fine. But in the main loop whenever the threads are created, each time loading cascade file does not seem good for performance. So my question is why the program stops when threads have common cascade file?

Comment: hmm are you trying to split it into 4 patches ? in that case your numbers are wrong (Thread b).  also, why only 3 threads/patches then ? and it won't work ever, if the face is right in the middle of your original image, since each of the Threads only sees a part of it

Comment: I am dividing one frame ( image) into three parts. thread a for left half, thread c for right half, thread b for the case when face is on the diversion line of a's area and c's area. Check the parameters of Rect(). This is actually working perfectly when the threads have their own classifier files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there is a dead lock. I suspect the function CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale is responsible. First of all, you have one and the **same cascadeClassifier** for several threads. When these threads invoke detectMultiScale, they invoke it on the **same instance**.
(It's like using the same file handle in different threads where all operations go to the same file.)

Further detectMultiScale is already multithreaded / parallelized.
In the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html?highlight=cascadeclassifier#cascadeclassifier) it says

> The function is parallelized with the TBB library.

so it is likely possible that you dead lock the only instance of CascadeClassifier by invoking detectMultiScale several times from different threads.

By the way, this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285480/opencv-cascadeclassifier-c-interface-in-multiple-threads) may help you further